# Laravel 5.4 mix version issue

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-mix

I have a project that has about 10 javascript files. I want to use Laravel mix webpack to combine and version the js files. The files get combined but the versioning is not working. It only works for my scss files. It used to work in Laravel elixir. I checked the mix-manifest.json file in the public directory and this is what I found:

```
{
  "mix.js": "mix.b2328beb0372c051d06d.js",
  "/css/main.css": "/css/main.bb97b313cc88fe75b545.css",
  "/js/main.js": "/js/main.js"
}
```

I looked for the mix.js file and I could not find it anywhere in my project.

Here is my webpack.mix.js file:

```
mix.combine(
    [
        'resources/assets/js/jRespond.js',
        'resources/assets/js/sweetalert.min.js',
        ....
    ]
    , 'public/js/main.js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/main.scss', 'public/css/main.css')
    .version();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The versioning doesn't seem to work correct for `combine` method indeed but using the `js` method should do the trick:

```
mix.js(
[
    'resources/assets/js/jRespond.js',
    'resources/assets/js/sweetalert.min.js',
    ....
]
, 'public/js/main.js')
.sass('resources/assets/sass/main.scss', 'public/css/main.css')
.version();
```

Comment: The reason I'm using combine because mix.js does not work with the plugins I'm using. when I use mix.js everything is compiled correctly, but in the browser there are so many errors. For example, I'm using a plugin called MatchHeight. This plugin works fine if I use combine or even the old elixir. But using mix.js, I check chrome dev tools and I see that the matchheight is not a function error. I'm also loading jquery 2.1.4 before my scripts, bootstrap complain that I need to load a version higher than 1.9.1. I'm not sure what's going on

Comment: Then you might want to contact the developers at Laravel since the fact that `version` doesn't work for `combine` looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I just had to update my Laravel-mix to a newer version. Jeffery Way added the versioning for mix.combine and mix.scripts